# Save date in America Pacific timezone format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, timezone

I'm trying to save date in the America Pacific timezone format. I execute before querying the following query

```
SET time_zone='-09:00'
```

but when I close the connection and reopen it then the date seems in the local format. Do you know why?

Comment: Pacific is either -8 or -7.  Never -9.  You should use `America/Los_Angeles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MySQL Documentation on Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)

`SET time_zone = timezone;` is a per connection setting and so when connection resets, it's resets to default value.

> Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time
>   zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially, the
>   session variable takes its value from the global time_zone variable,
>   but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>
> mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;

If you want to set it globally then you can either

Change the configuration file (`.cnf` file) to reflect the change

(OR)

If you have `SUPER` privilege then you can set the global server time zone value at runtime with the command below

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit your my.cnf and reboot to set it permanently.

essentially you'll want to add this line to /etc/my.cnf

```
default_time_zone='-09:00'
```

See these articles for more details.

[How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone